# Online IPhone device testing

Tags: iphone, testing, device

I have read that we can do online testing of our application on a real IPhone device.
But we have to pay for it..

Actually i have seen this working in my last office but i was missed to ask this procedure....
and now i have no link with them.

Please provide some more info towards this..and a link will be very helpful...

Comment: What do you mean online testing? You can access the internet through the simulator.

Comment: @Jonathan---Are you joking or serious..?....I am asking about Testing on  real devices ...Which are available online...on a distinct place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its an actual iPhone app written in objective c you have to have a developer licence. this will cost $99 or £50. That will let you test your application on upto 100 devices.

Comment: OK ..but who will provide this? Any link will be useful

Comment: developer.apple.com... come on - do you want me to do it all for you?

Comment: Sorry but i never noticed that second option in https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/
but thanks.......

Answer (score 10):

You can try on device anywhere

http://www.deviceanywhere.com/

They provide online real device for testing..

Thx
Mit

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Mitesh Khatri,

Device Anywhere is the tool, where the real device is connected and a user can connect to the device remotely and perform all actions as if done on the real device, install the app and test.

There are limitations though. Go through their website and blog. Below are the links

website link already provided by Mitesh.

http://deviceanywhere.typepad.com/

http://www.youtube.com/user/DeviceAnywhere

Answer (score 0):

Try here:

https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/